# yarn eg:'live-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I am using yarn **v1.6.0** as a dependency manager, I have installed  *live-server* globally by using the following command:
`yarn global-add live-server`

But when executed it like `live server`, it is giving the following error:

> 'live-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

It is obvious my path is not configured Can some help which path should I use an environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly check your computer whether the `node.js` is installed or not (if not: downloaded from internet)(command promt)
2. After installed the `node.js` go to command prompt type `npm install -g live-server` (command promt).
3. Go to vs code (help>new terminal) and then type: `set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`
4. After execuction type:`Get-ExecutionPolicy`.
5. Again execution type:`Get-ExecutionPolicy -list`.
6. After that type : `live-server`.
7. Done

problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to see my version of live-server but got this error,You can use

> **npm install -g live-server**

in your npm command line

Answer (score 4):

All the packages you download from *yarn* gets stored in **bin** folder inside *yarn* directory. So, you have to set the path of the *bin* folder of your *yarn* in **PATH** environment variable as you might have did with the *bin* directory of the *npm*.
1). The following path would get you to the *bin* folder in *Windows* machine then set this path to the **PATH** environment variable.
**C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin**
2). For macOS do the following
**$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.yarn/bin/**

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `path` of the bin of the yarn.

```
C:\Users\USER NAME\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
```

Go to the `Environment variables`.

Select, path -> new -> paste the copied `path`.

Reopen the cmd and type

```
live-server -v
```